# Undefined Index configuration JSON elements in multiple files

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode JSON elements in multiple files using the following JSON

```
configurationItems":[  
      {  
         "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
         "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2015-01-12T16:44:03.358Z",
         "configurationStateId":126,
         "relatedEvents":[  ],
         "awsAccountId":"",
         "configurationItemStatus":"ResourceDeleted",
         "resourceId":"i-20faebca",
         "configurationStateMd5Hash":"",
         "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "tags":{  },
         "relationships":[  ]
      },
      {  
         "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
         "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2015-01-12T16:33:51.495Z",
         "configurationStateId":1,
         "relatedEvents":[  ],
         "awsAccountId":"",
         "configurationItemStatus":"ResourceDiscovered",
         "resourceId":"",
         "ARN":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:037734006438:instance/i-231a43d8",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "availabilityZone":"us-east-1c",
         "configurationStateMd5Hash":"",
         "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "resourceCreationTime":"2015-01-12T16:29:22.000Z",
         "tags":{  },
         "relationships":[  ],
         "configuration":{  
            "instanceId":"",
            "imageId":"",
            "state":{  
               "code":16,
               "name":"running"
            },
```

I know the reason I am getting the undefined index error is because the first entry has no configuration element my question is how to handle this in my code ? my PHP script is as follows :

```
<?php 


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array(); 

$result='' ;
foreach(glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\views\*.json') as $filename) {$json = file_get_contents($filename);


if($json!=null)
{ 
    $decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
    //$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
    //$ss=$decode["array"]; 
    //echo $decoded['number']; 

    if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
    { 
    foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
    //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 
     $cfi= $configurationItems["configuration"];
        if(isset($cfi["instanceId"]) && isset($cfi["imageId"])&& isset($cfi["privateDnsName"] //repeat for all elements))
{

    // all defined and echoed as



   $ebsOptimized=$configurationItems["configuration"]["ebsOptimized"]; 
    echo "ebsOptimized:",$ebsOptimized,"<br />";



$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     configuration(instance_id, image_id, private_dns_name, public_dns_name, key_name, state_transition_reason, ami_launch_index, instance_type, launch_time, kernel_id, subnet_id, vpc_id, private_ip_address,architecture, root_device_type, root_device_name, virtualisation_type, client_token, source_dest_check, hypervisor, ebs_optimised)


VALUES('$instanceId','$imageId', '$privateDnsName' , '$publicDnsName', '$keyName', '$stateTransitionReason', '$amiLaunchIndex', '$instanceType', '$launchTime', '$kernelId', '$subnetId', '$vpcId', '$privateIpAddress', '$architecture', '$rootDeviceType', '$rootDeviceName', '$virtualizationType', '$clientToken', '$sourceDestCheck', '$hypervisor', '$ebsOptimized')")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));; 

    }// check if row inserted or not 
    if ($result) { 
        // successfully inserted into database 
        $response["code"] = 1; 
        $response["message"] = "successfully updated config table "; 

        // echoing JSON response 
        echo json_encode($response); 
    } else { 
        // failed to insert row 
        $response["code"] = 2; 
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

        // echoing JSON response 
        echo json_encode($response); 
    } 

    } 
    } 

}

?>
```

Comment: Would be good if the code is reduced to minimum.

Comment: @Daenarys understood have edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too long , you can check your indexes like this

For **php**

```
  if(isset($array['yourindex'])){
     //do your stuff 
    }
```

For **Javascript**

```
if (typeof yourJsonObject.yourIndex != 'undefined') {
 // do your stuff 
}
```

Comment: my thought was [$cfi= isset($configurationItems["configuration"]) ? $configurationItems["configuration"] : ''; ] but that does not seem to make a difference any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try like this [$cfi= isset($configurationItems->configuration) ? $configurationItems->configuration : ''; ]

Comment: thanks I did that just returns blank error ie no variables just to clarify I am putting the code a line above the if isset correct ? replacing cfi